# Name error disappears on print in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to write code in python to generate all permutations of an input string.

```
inp = raw_input()

out = [inp[0]]
for i in range(1,len(inp)):
   #print [range(len(j)+1) for j in out]
   out = [j[:k]+inp[i]+j[k:] for k in range(len(j)+1) for j in out]

print out
```

For an input 'abc', it outputs

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "perm.py", line 6, in
>
> ```
> out = [j[:k]+inp[i]+j[k:] for k in range(len(j)+1) for j in out]
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'j' is not defined
>
> shell returned 1

If I uncomment line 5, and the code looks like

```
inp = raw_input()

out = [inp[0]]
for i in range(1,len(inp)):
   print [range(len(j)+1) for j in out]
   out = [j[:k]+inp[i]+j[k:] for k in range(len(j)+1) for j in out]

print out
```

For an input 'abc', it outputs

> [[0, 1]]
>
> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
>
> ['cba', 'cab', 'bca', 'acb', 'bac','abc']

**What sorcery is this?**

Comment: @MartijnPieters But wasn't that just for the list comprehension used during the print? And if you say I have to explicitly define them, what about 'k'?

Comment: I meant that in your list comprehension you get a name error for `j` because it isn't assigned to yet when `range(len(j)+1)` executes, *unless* you include your `print` statement, which has a list comprehension assigning to `j`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have your list comprehension loops back to front; you need to list them in nesting order from left to right, so your `for j in out` needs to come *first*

```
out = [j[:k]+inp[i]+j[k:] for j in out for k in range(len(j)+1)]
```

The `print` statement list comprehension defined a `j` name for your version to loop over; in Python 2, a list comprehension does not have their own scope so the `for` loop target is accessible after the loop completes just like with a regular `for` loop. This has changed in Python 3, where list comprehensions now get their own scope, just like dict and set comprehensions and generator expressions.

If it helps, write out the list comprehensions as regular loops first; your code did this:

```
tmp = []
for j in out:
    tmp.append(range(len(j)+1))
print tmp

out = []
for k in range(len(j)+1):
    for j in out:
        out.append(j[:k]+inp[i]+j[k:])
```

where the `range(len(j)+1)` expression *only* works because you have used `j` as a `for` loop target in the preceding expression building `tmp` for `print`.

You may be treating this as a coding exercise, but the standard library already includes a function that produces permutations: [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

inp = raw_input()
print list(permutations(inp))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations('abc'))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Comment: Yeah, this was for illustrating list comprehensions to someone else. -_- 
Ended up learning something myself.